# Formatting/escaping an MDX query within a nested OPENQUERY call

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

This is a pretty specific and sophisticated use case, but my team and I are trying to make our cube deployment architecture much more flexible between our linked servers (without resorting to PowerShell).

I've been slowly trying to chip away at hard-coded linked server references and ran into a pretty bad blocker.

Our code used to look something like this and has worked half decently until attempting to make it dynamic (indented for readability):

```
-- Run from DB_SRV1 as a stored procedure...

SELECT
...
FROM 
  OPENQUERY(DB_SRV2, 
            'SELECT * 
             FROM OPENQUERY(
                    SRV2_ANALYSISSERVICES_REPORT,
                    ''CALL ASSP.DiscoverXMLMetadataFull("Database\DataSources\DataSource");'')') a 
INNER JOIN 
    db_cache..tblCubeDBRelation b ON a.parent_databaseid=b.parent_databaseId
INNER JOIN 
    db_cache..tblCubeStatus on b.parent_databaseid=DatabaseName and SourceDatabaseName='SRV1'
```

This worked great for processing across two fixed Analysis Services instances for a production environment, but it proved to be pretty limiting for building out a testing/development environment with several instances; especially since we can allocate threads across each instance more effectively during processing. Attempting to make the nested OPENQUERY statements dynamic:

```
-- Run from DB_SRV1 as a stored procedure...

DECLARE @DBConn varchar(50);
DECLARE @ASDataSource nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @MDXQuery nvarchar(50);

-- Ideally configurable to run processing on any AS instance
-- Hard-coded for testing here...
SET @DBConn = 'SRV2_DB';
SET @ASDataSource = 'SRV2\ASInstance_v3';

DECLARE @DataSourceQuery nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @DataSourceResults nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

SET @ParmDefinition = '@s nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT';
SET @DataSourceQuery = 
      'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([' + @DBConn + '],
          ''SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(
               ['+ @ASDataSource +'], 
               ''CALL ASSP.DiscoverXMLMetadataFull("Database\DataSources\DataSource");''))
          ''
      ';

EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @DataSourceQuery,
    @ParmDefinition,
    @S = @DataSourceResults OUTPUT;
    SELECT @DataSourceResults;
```

I learned the hard way that you have to [do some hackery to parameterize an OPENQUERY call](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1a23ece4-386b-497b-b1b5-a081724fe543/select-from-exec?forum=transactsql). I'm struggling with nesting the MDX query inside this mess, so I'm consistently returning:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'CALL'.
```

Any help or pointers on escaping this would be greatly appreciated- thanks in advance for making any sort of attempt to read through!

Comment: Interesting question. We gave up on OPENQUERY and now use the stored procedure from this project https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/